# How to get a script file to accept user name thru dialog box, save name, but have a different script operate from that point on

Tags: scripting, applescript

I am attempting to accept a user name through an Applescript script:  I have accomplished this. So I am thinking that I need to have the name saved to a file because thats all i need and have another piece of script activate every time I click on the app from that point and retrieve the name.  My question is how would I get it to not accept the original script after the first run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AppleScript Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html)
| [Scripting with AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/work_with_as.html)

---

One way would be to use properties.

```
property MyUserName : ""

if MyUserName is "" then

    display dialog "User Name:" default answer "" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue…"} default button 2 with icon 0
    copy the result as list to {button_pressed, text_returned}

    if button_pressed is "Cancel" then
        beep
        return
    end if

    if text_returned is not "" then set MyUserName to text_returned

else

    display dialog "Stored user name: " & MyUserName buttons {"Ok"} default button 1 with icon 1

end if
```

The property-value is stored within the compiled script. It also works when the script is saved as an application. Opening and recompiling it in AppleScript Editor resets the values.

Comment: So, the username in this script is saved  but when script is turned into an app, it will not ask for the name a second time?

Comment: As long as the property MyUserName is empty ("") the script executes the first part and if MyUserName isn't empty it executes the second part (the part after else). The property (or better: the value of the property) will be preserved until you compile the script again. You can test that in the editor: as soon you change something in the script and execute it it gets compiled again and MyUserName is empty again. I stored the script as application (after I executed it and supplied an user name) and funny enough, it still had that value preserved.